# Balance reaction equation for stabilised PAN cylisation reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers

I am dealing with polymer chemistry and trying to balance one of these reaction steps. I have read a lot about the cyclisation reaction step but it is not clear to me how to balance these equations or what happens between the *first step* A) and B1) *cyclised form* of polyacrylonitril?

[image: reactions]

By looking at the image and counting the H- and C-atoms, I can tell that polyacrylonitril in the first step has 13 H-atoms (the same amount of C-atoms like the cyclised structure) while the cyclised structure gives 15 H-atoms. Can someone help me to balance or comment on this or what is missing in this part?

P.s.: I know that it is an increasing polymer chain but I just would like to truncate it to this step.

Comment: Author of this picture didn't feel the need to keep it to the same fragment of the polymer.

Comment: So which part is missing in order to get from A) to B1)?I know that B1) can have more C- and H-atoms but I need to know which fragment is missing. I was thinking of a Diels-Alder similiar reaction (even if this is another mechanism) but I am not sure which fragment should be added and increases the polymer chain.

Comment: _sigh_ Minimally left or right. It's simple polymerisation of CN groups.